# showing data from database into tkinter not working

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I have defined a function here and it is supposed to work correctly because im using a similar function somewhere else but without giving any conditions(where.. like or regexp) and it works fine there, when i use regexp and all it does not give an output. Why is that? Thanks in advance :)

Code:

```
def search():
    log = Toplevel(root)
    log.title('View all customers')
    def db():  
        selected = drop.get()
        result_win = Toplevel(log)
        result_win.title('Search result')

        con = mysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root',
                                password='*****', database='BOOK')
        c = con.cursor()

        c.execute(f"SELECT * from books where '{selected}' regexp 
        '{e_sch.get()}';")
        result = c.fetchall()
        index=0
        for index, x in enumerate(result):
            num = 0
            for y in x:
                lookup_label = Label(result_win, text=y)
                lookup_label.grid(row=index+1, column=num)
                num +=1
        con.close()        
        l1 = Label(result_win,text='Sl.No',font=font_text)
        l2 = Label(result_win,text='Title',font=font_text)
        l3 = Label(result_win,text='Authors',font=font_text)
        l4 = Label(result_win,text='Subject',font=font_text)
        l5 = Label(result_win,text='Availablity',font=font_text)
        btn_ext = Button(result_win,text='Exit',font=font_text,command=result_win.destroy,borderwidth=2,fg='#eb4d4b')

        l1.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=20)
        l2.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=20)
        l3.grid(row=0,column=2,padx=20)
        l4.grid(row=0,column=3,padx=20)
        l5.grid(row=0,column=4,padx=20)
        btn_ext.grid(row=index+2,columnspan=7,ipadx=540)

    global a
    l = Label(log,text='Search',font=Font(family='helvetica', size='20'))
    drop = ttk.Combobox(log,value=['Search by....','Sl.no','Title','Authors','Subject','Availablity'])
    drop.current(0)
    l2 = Label(log,text='Enter',font=font_text)
    e_sch = Entry(log)
    b_sch = Button(log, text='Search book', command=db, font=font_text) 
    b_ext = Button(log, text='Exit', command=log.destroy, font=font_text) 
    a = drop.get()
    l.grid(row=0,columnspan=3,pady=20)
    drop.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=3)
    l2.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=(20,0))
    e_sch.grid(row=2,column=1, padx=30, ipady=5,pady=20)
    b_sch.grid(row=3,column=0,columnspan=3,ipadx=200)
    b_ext.grid(row=4,column=0,columnspan=3,ipadx=237)
```

Sometimes i get this error too `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'index' referenced before assignment`

Comment: I think `SELECT ... where '{selected}' ...` should be `SELECT ... where \`{selected}\` ...` instead.

Comment: please add that as an asnwer to i can mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of the SELECT statement is incorrect:

```
SELECT * from books where '{selected}' regexp '{e_sch.get()}';
```

should be:

```
SELECT * from books where `{selected}` regexp '{e_sch.get()}';
```

Field name should be surrounded by ``, not `''`.